# How to perform an action if a specific VIN is in my MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working with Autocheck who has no knowledge regarding PHP at all. I have a page created where I have to send a customer to a page when they click on a link. The page that is displayed has to show the Autocheck Vehicle History Report.

I have created the page and have the link working exactly how I want it to. What I have to do is on the Autocheck page, set it up so that the Vehicle history report only shows if the VIN number is in my database. If it is not in my Database, I can show an error message.

What I have currently for my page is the following:

```
<?php
session_start();

$post_data = array();
$post_data['VIN'] = $_GET['vin'];
$post_data['CID'] = 'CID';
$post_data['PWD'] = 'PASSWORD';
$post_data['SID'] = 'SID';
//build the post string
foreach($post_data AS $key => $val){
$poststring .= urlencode($key) . "=" . urlencode($val) . "&";
}
// strip off trailing ampersand
$poststring = substr($poststring, 0, -1);
// create a new CURL resource
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
"https://www.autocheck.com/DealerWebLink.jsp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $poststring);
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);
// close CURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Lastly, my VIN numbers are in the following row in my DB:

post_meta['vin-number']

If any help can be provided that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have sample JSON output from the cURL call?

Comment: Hi - In the above code has CID, PWD, and SID. My question is one of my website users they have one vehicle info page on my website and they want to provide free vehicle history reports for their page visitors from their AutoCheck account.
So Which detail do I need to get from this user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a VIN check before you proceed.

This is just an indication, as the code will depend on what your database is, how it is organized, how it is accessed, and so on. You will need for `$conn` to be a working PDO connection to the database, etc.:

```
$post_data['VIN'] = $_GET['vin'];

$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM whateverDb.whateverTable WHERE vinColumn = :vin');
$query->bindValue(':vin', $post_data['VIN']);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

...now inspect rows (possibly empty if no VIN in DB).
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something wrong but when I test this,  I get a 500 error.

Comment: How did you 'test' this indication? Add the code to your question.

Comment: Hi LSerni - In the above code has CID, PWD, and SID. My question is one of my website users they have one vehicle info page on my website and they want to provide free vehicle history reports for their page visitors from their AutoCheck account.
So Which detail do I need to get from this user?